# How do I abort a currently active SVN merge?

Tags: svn

I performed an SVN merge while I had uncommitted changes to some files.  I had forgotten about the uncommitted changes, so I'd like to abort the merge.  Having noted the conflict, SVN is currently asking me to select from the options

```
Select: (p) postpone, (df) show diff, (e) edit file, (m) merge,
        (mc) my side of conflict, (tc) their side of conflict,
        (s) show all options:
```

None of these are equivalent to "abort" from what I can tell (nor are any of the options shown with (s)).  How do I back out of this?  Is it safe to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>?

Answer (score 1):

The `q` option will postpone all remaining conflicts and not leave file traces the way that choosing `p` (postpone) for each conflict will.

Answer (score 0):

From the name, I had assumed that "(p) postpone" would cycle through the conflicting files, asking me to take action on each one.  Instead, after searching through the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.pdf) (which does not have an index entry for "postpone"), I found that it's the first step in the closest thing I can find to an "abort" process.

Choosing "postpone" *will* alter the non-conflict files in your working copy according to the merge, so it's not a true abort.  However, it will return you to the command prompt with three additional files in the working copy

```
filename.working
filename.rOLDREV
filename.rNEWREV
```

for each file `filename` that had a merge conflict.  This is from the "Basic Usage" section of the docs, page 29/pdf page 50 of the above link for SVN 1.7.  That document refers `filename.mine` instead of `filename.working`, so evidently this was some sort of change between versions.

From here, you can use command-line commands to return your working copy to its state before you attempted the merge.  For example, assume you attempted a merge

$ svn merge -r NEWREV:OLDREV ^/branches/testing/ .

from the root of your working copy of the `testing` branch after forgetting that you have uncommitted changes in `testing/filename`.  When the conflict interrupts the merge, select "(p) postpone" to return to the command prompt.  `testing/filename.mine` is the file you want to keep - the file in its working-copy state before the merge.  Move it to your home folder or somewhere similar for safekeeping.

Most of the files in your working copy will be equal to their OLDREV versions.

**NOTE*: at this point, I had finished writing this answer and tried to submit it.  Stack Overflow presented me with a CAPTCHA overlay that did not have a CAPTCHA box because I wasn't allowing the correct JavaScript for it.  I allowed the JavaScript and reloaded the page, which wiped the rest of my answer that hadn't been saved, and no way I'm rewriting it.

Comment: Just to note, the documentation you linked is a few versions behind (you linked 1.7, while 1.10 is the current version).  [Here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve.pending) is the documentation on _postpone_.